# Connection between 2 enum in symfony/php

Tags: php, symfony, enums

I have 2 classes extends from enum class:
each of them looks like :

```
class firstEnum extends Enum{

    const x= 1;

    const y= 2;

    const z= 5;

    const w= 6;


}

class secondEnum extends Enum{

    const a= 1;

    const b= 2;


}
```

I need to get the "a" from second enum depend the first one

for example: I have got from the user the param: 1 and go to first enum and get the const "x"

and now i need to get the const "a" depend the number of x 
how can I do that?

Comment: For now  I have only one question "WHY would you do this?" Sounds like misusage of constants. But really, please, provide more case info. May be we can offer you another solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static method, which will... eem, return you the argument you pass to it?!

```
public static function getTheOne($searchValue)
{
    foreach ([
        self::a,
        self::b,
    ] as $value) {
        if ($searchValue == $value) {
            return $value; // makes no sense
        }
    }
}
```

But this sounds pointless. So, what is your aim? May be you need to have a configuration in your class and have a similar method, which would return you some key/name for the curtain value?

```
private static $validValues = [
    'value #1' => 1,
    'value #2' => 2,
];

public static function getTheOne($searchValue)
{
    foreach (self::$validValues as $key => $value) {
        if ($searchValue == $value) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
}
```